# Authorization error with Team Foundation and Hudson (and TeamCity)

Tags: tfs, hudson, authorization, teamcity

I've browsed every post about TFS and Hudson I could find but nothing useful has popped up.

In Hudson when I attempt a build, the console output provides:

> Started by user jlowder
>   [workspace] $ tf workspaces -format:brief -server:http://ashpteam01.hq.hanger.com:8080 ********
>   TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://ashpteam01.hq.hanger.com:8080/.
>   FATAL: Executable returned an unexpected result code [100]
>   ERROR: null
>   [DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: NextGen Automation #25 due to result: FAILURE
>   Finished: FAILURE

If I manually run the tf command above from a command prompt, it works.  I access TF from Visual Studio 2010 just fine.

I receive this error regardless if an attempt to access TFS comes from Hudson or Team City.  My login to TFS is my domain user name and password, which I have checked and re-checked.

What am I missing here?

Comment: silly question - how are you running hudson?  as a service?  if so under what account?

Comment: I'm running it as a service and now running it under my domain account.

Comment: You can run Jenkins/Hudson interactively as yourself to test things.  I'd try that first to attempt repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the domain the server was running on would not send back to the domain I was requesting from.  Moving hudson and tfs to same domain

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Control Panel > Network Passwords, are there any saved passwords there for your server? TFS will always try and authenticate using these first. If one is saved, and it is incorrect - you will get this error.

Also, what URL do you connect to in Visual Studio? Does it have a /tfs/ on the end?

Comment: I tried the URL with and without /tfs and nothing changed in the error.   So both: http://domain.hq.hanger.com/tfs:8080 and http://domain.hq.hanger.com:8080 failed.  As for network passwords, are you talking about the tfs server?  I don't have access to that machine but can ask